# Ошибка Android studio - Failed to complete gradle execution

Tags: android-studio, java, android, gradle

При попытке запустить созданный простейший проект, когда уже выбрал виртуальное устройство, выскакивает сообщение об ошибке - Failed to complete gradle execution
[image: link]

Вот пишет в Gradle Console

> Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException:
> >     Failed to run command:
> >     C:...\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex
> >     --output C:...\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.2-255816edbbf414e2d0b1a5ac3a093bcb291d606e.jar
> >     C:...\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.2\libs\internal_impl-21.0.2.jar
> >     Error Code: 1 Output: Try: Run with
> >     --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
> >     option to get more log output. BUILD
> >     FAILED

Ошибки в Gradle не подсвечивает

Comment: Зайдите в градл файл проекта и посмотрите, не подсвечивает ли он там на ошибки.

Comment: Ошибки в Gradle не подсвечивает

Comment: Попробуйте для начала нажать на кнопку Sync Gradle + Clean Project + Caches/Restart

Comment: @tolik23, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, ему недостаточно памяти, попробуйте в настройках File-->Setting-->Gradle-- в окне Gradle Vm Option добавить -Xmx256m.

Такая ошибка была в версии Tool 24.0.0, в новых версиях ее пофиксили.
Проблема в файле tools/lib/find_java.bat в строке 27 лишний пробел после arch_ext=32  `find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64`. Правильный запрос выглядит так `find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64`.

Comment: Да вот фиг знает, что ему нужно, я увеличил память. Первое время порботал, абы как, потом снова эта же ошибка. Короче, это пляска с бубном. Я уменьшал-увеличивал память, как-то и когда-то, в какой-то момент может заработать. Потом снова все полетит.

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте новый build-tools (на текущий момент 21.1.2 актуален) и в build.gradle поменяйте buildToolsVersion "21.0.2" на "21.1.2". Тут проблема не в gradle, т.к. он просто делает сборку, используя ресурсы, а, скорее всего, в криво ставшем SDK. На всякий случай переместите SDK в корень директории, хотя в AS, вроде, поправили проблему кодировки, но я особо не проверял.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же ошибка. При помощи системы контроля версий установил что проблема в файле dimens.xml

Вместо
`<dimen name="map_search_view_top_margin">100dp</dimen>`
использовал
`<dimen name="map_search_view_top_margin">100</dimen>`
(разница в отсутствии `dp`).

Возможно кому-то поможет.